# Scan network for any connected node

Tags: ip, subnet

Good day

On a network with limited monitoring tools and limited management, how would I use Zenmap or Wireshark to locate nodes on the network.

Using 192.168.16.0/24 on Zenmap, only scans one subnet, I need to see any node. Say if it has a different IP or if it is using APIPA.

Is it possible? Any remark would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how limited your management is, but you can see what machines are connected to a network by viewing switch side ARP tables. This will give you a MAC address > IP address relationship, regardless of subnet.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M : a L2 switch does not have an arp table. It does have a mac address table where you will find all the MAC addresses of the devices (that are transmitting) on your network but not the ip addresses. If it is a L3 switch then it will have an arp table but it will still not contain **all** ip addresses on the network, only the ones the switch has recently sent traffic to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can install arp-scan, you could do

```
arp-scan 10.0.0.0/8
arp-scan 172.16.0.0/12
arp-scan 192.168.0.0/16
```

Similarily, this works in nmap as well:

```
nmap -sn 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
```

Then the hosts would need to react to ping, though.

Of course if you want to scan for EVERY IP it would take way longer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use "192.168.0.0/16" in Zenmap to scan other subnets.
2. If you prefer windows software, you also can use WFilter's "network scan extension" to scan clients in network.